# C operand ~and a char

Tags: c, macos, operand, negation

I would like to know what the ~ operand does with a char. Example code: the output is -1 if var="a".

```
int ret (char var)
{
   int x;
   x=var|~var;
   return x;
}
int main()
{
  printf("%d",ret("a"));
  return 0;
}
```

I dont understand why it returns -1

Comment: Do you know what the `~` operator does?

Comment: Operator ~ in theory, puts a 0 where is a 1, and a 1 where is a 0.

Comment: ASCII(a) --> 97.  97 + -98 --> -1.  `-37` looks strange.

Comment: @chux could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Are you certain `char var = 'a';` in a windows based pc outputs -37?

Comment: I'm very surprised that you'd get `-37` on Windows. That's what I'd expect for `char var = '$';`.

Comment: Double check your Windows code, you may defined `var` as `char var = "a";`, which may get such strange result.

Comment: The `-98` is easy to explain, `-37` is not.  `'a'` has the ASCII code of 97 which is certainly the value assigned via `char var = 'a';`.  `~var` takes the bit-wise inverse.  Since `var`, a `char` is likely smaller is _size_ than  `int`, `var` is converted (or promoted)  - always fuzzy on this) to an `int`.  The result is still 97 or 0b01100001, but likely 32-bits wide (maybe 64 or 16, etc.)  0b00000000_00000000_00000000_01100001.  Now `~` is applied, giving an `int` with something like a`0b11111111_11111111_11111111_10011110`.  This value is passed to `printf()`.

Comment: Given a typical 2's Compliment notation, the result is -98.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it cannot readily be reproduced and OP has not supplied needed clarification.

Comment: i dont see that this is 'off topic' it asks what an operator (slightly obscure one) does. This is perfectly valid. That the question is a little messy is different

Comment: The question is about type promotion. char does not exist as an `expression` , so it is promoted to an int.

Comment: Why was this closed? Perhaps not a very good question, but it's most certainly about programming.

Comment: When `ret("a")` is called, it passed the _address_ of the string `"a"`.  Within `int ret (char var)`, `var` takes on a partial value of that address.  It is partial as an address certainly will not fit in `char`.  Strongly suspect you meant `ret(`a`)`.  (single quote vs double quote.)  Please clarify your interest.

Comment: Regardless of what value is in `var`, `x = var | ~var;` will certainly result in `-1`.  `~var` result in a signed extension of the bit-wise negation of `var`.  So if `var` is 0b01100001 (and int is 32-bit), then `~var` is 0x11111111_11111111_11111111_10011110.  The `|` of these 2 is then `0x11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111` and that bit pattern is returned.  As `int` is very often coded as 2's complement, this bit pattern prints out as `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

First `"a"` and `'a'` are different. `"a"` passes the **address** of string array `"a"` and `'a'` passes the char `a`. So you need to modify the code as

```
printf("%d",ret('a'));
```

Once modified, `var` is `97` which is `0x00000061` and `~var` is `-98` which is `0xffffff9e`.

`0x00000061` | `0xffffff9e` will be `0xffffffff` that will be '-1' by [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

If you want `0xffffffff`, use `%x` instead as

```
printf("0x%x",ret('a'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `~` operator is the `negation` operator which has the identity `-x-1`. There is both a logical (bitwise) negation and an arithmetic negation. C implements an arithmetic negation with the `~`. Take for example `x=5`in binary:

```
x = 5
```

The the `~` operation would have the following effect:

```
~x = -5-1 = -6
```

In your case `'a'` is `97` or `01100001`, therefore

```
~a = -97-1  (or -98)
```

Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I'd expect `~a` to return an `int`, maybe 32 bits long.

Comment: See these `1100001` bits? *Count them*. Do you miss anything?

Comment: you have forgotten a number: `97` is `01100001`, therefore `~a=10011110` or `158`

Comment: `~` incurs the usual integer promotions.  Thus I'd expect `char var = 'a';  `~var` to be `FFFFFF9E` in hex (4-byte `int`).

Comment: @chux: bear in mind that `char` be signed or unsigned.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth True that `char` may be signed or unsigned.  In this case, I see no difference in `~var`.  `~var` still ends up as a bit pattern of "lots of 1s" (depending on `int` bit width) then `10011110` .

Comment: Refinement: "The ~ operator is the not operator ... and has the identity -x-1".  That '~' typically has the property `-x-1` is a reflection of 2's complement integer notation.  Though this is not specified to be so in C, it is a rare machine in 2014, this would not hold.